# apache2 and <LocationMatch> with negative regular expression

Tags: apache

I have a question.

```
<LocationMatch "^/([^/]+)/login">
   ...
</LocationMatch>
```

Now I need to delete from the LocationMatch specific path.

for example:

/ProjectTrue1/login - it is need

/ProjectTrue1/login - it is need

/ProjectFalse1/login - it is not need

Sorry for the my bad English and my bad explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LocationMatch "^/(?!(ProjectFalse1|ProjectFalse2|...)[^/]+/login

unclear if you meant for there to a pattern for the non-matching projects.